# How to configure traefik on docker for ssl on primary and sub domain?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm trying to setup sub-domain along with wildcard https support on sub-domain along with primary domain.

I've made it work for primary domain as below:

https://gist.github.com/sujit-baniya/3a7f2554e269d280a5d98c932e91ebcb

Now I'm not sure on how I could setup https on sub-domains.

In docker-compose.yml, I've tried changing line to

> "traefik.http.routers.app.rule=Host(`example.${DOMAIN}`)"

But on building it's resulting in Invalid Certificate.

Please suggest on how would I get it working